# Monitor bandwidth usage using Nagios Core

Tags: networking, network-programming, nagios

How can we monitor the network bandwidth usage using Nagios Core?

I have installed the Nagios Core on Ubuntu 12.04 and NsClient++ window agent on my window system. Now I want to monitor my system bandwith usage. Can any one please provide me the steps to configure it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Check the plugin "check_nt" present on nagios server. Most probably the path is /usr/local/nagios/libexec.

This link, may help you on this.

> https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Windows/Check-Windows-Network-Traffic-2FUsage/details